# Prove equation in complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers, solution-verification

Prove that for all $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ following equation is satisfied:
$$
\sqrt z=\sqrt{|z|}\frac{|z|+z}{||z|+z|}
$$

Here's what I've got so far:
$$
\sqrt z \cdot ||z|+z|=\sqrt{|z|}\cdot(|z|+z)
$$

Now I square both sides:
$$
z \cdot (|z|+z)^2=|z|\cdot(|z|+z)^2
$$
Therefore:
$$
z=|z|
$$
Which obviously isn't true for all of $z$ from the given set.

How to prove this correctly? Where did I made the mistake?

Comment: $|x|^2=x^2$ is correct for *real* numbers $x$, but not for complex numbers. So when you square $\sqrt z\cdot||z|+z|$, you get $z\cdot||z|+z|^2$ not $z\cdot(|z|+z)^2$.

Comment: It's also important to specify *which* square root $\sqrt z$ refers to. There are two conventions; the equation can only hold for one of them.

Comment: @BarryCipra I don't have any further informations about this exercise, but probably only one these root interpretations satisfies the equation, and if both, then I think you can assume either of them. I have tried using polar form as Joe suggested, but didn't get far either. Do you have any tips on how to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We write $z$ as $z=R\cdot e^{ix}, R\neq 0$ so $\vert z\vert = R$ and $\overline{z} = \overline{R\cdot e^{ix}}=R\cdot e^{-ix}$ and notice that $\vert z\vert =\sqrt{z\cdot \overline{z}}$ .Starting from the $RHS$:
$$\sqrt{|z|}\frac{|z|+z}{||z|+z|}=\sqrt{R}\frac{R+R\cdot e^{ix}}{R\cdot|1+e^{ix}|}=\sqrt{R}\frac{1+\cdot e^{ix}}{\sqrt{\left(1+e^{ix}\right)\left(1+e^{-ix}\right)}}=\sqrt{R\cdot \frac{1+e^{ix}}{1+e^{-ix}}}=\sqrt z$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $z\in\Bbb C\setminus\Bbb R_{\le0}$, in particular $z\neq0$ so your equation equals
$$
\sqrt{\frac{z}{|z|}}=\frac{|z|+z}{||z|+z|}\;.
$$

Write now $z$ in polar form
$$
z=re^{i\theta}
$$
and substitute it in the previous equation will lead to
\begin{align*}
e^{i\left(\frac{\theta}2+k\pi\right)}
=\frac{r(1+e^{i\theta})}{|r(1+e^{i\theta})|}
=\frac{1+e^{i\theta}}{|1+e^{i\theta}|}\;,
\end{align*}

for $k=0,1$ according to the choice of the branch of the square root.

Can you go on from here?

Comment: ok, now I've  got $\sqrt{re^{i\phi}}|r(e^0+e^{i\phi})|=\sqrt r \cdot r(e^0+e^{i\phi})$ . What now?

Answer (score 1):

If $|z|+z\not=0$ (i.e., if $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\le0}$), then

$$\left(\sqrt{|z|}{|z|+z\over||z|+z|}\right)^2=|z|{(|z|+z)(|z|+z)\over(|z|+z)(|z|+\overline{z})}={|z|^2+z|z|\over|z|+\overline{z}}={z\overline{z}+z|z|\over|z|+\overline{z}}=z$$

Observing also that $|z|\gt|\Re(z)|$ (the real part of $z$) if $z\not\in\mathbb{R}$, so that $\Re(|z|+z)\gt0$ if $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\le0}$, it follows that

$$\sqrt{|z|}{|z|+z\over||z|+z|}=\sqrt z$$

with the function-defining convention that $\Re(\sqrt z)\gt0$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}_{\le0}$. (Note, this accords with $\sqrt{e^{i\theta}}=e^{i\theta/2}$ using the convention $-\pi\lt\theta\le\pi$, not the convention $0\le\theta\lt2\pi$.)

Answer (score 1):

I will show the geometric intuition behind this equality. To show the equality of two complex numbers, one can equally show the equality of their **(1) modules** and **(2) arguments**. Let $z\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \mathbb{R}_{\leq 0}$ such that $z=re^{i\phi}$.

**(1)** Equality of modules:
$$|\sqrt{z}|=\left| \sqrt{|z|}\frac{|z|+z}{||z|+z|}\right| $$
$$\sqrt{|z|}= \sqrt{|z|}\frac{\left||z|+z\right|}{||z|+z|}$$
$$\checkmark$$
**(2)** Due to **(1)** w.l.o.g let $|z|=1$. Let's check the equality of the arguments:
$$\text{Arg} \sqrt{z}=\text{Arg} \sqrt{e^{i\phi}}=\text{Arg}e^{i\frac{\phi}{2} }=\frac{\phi}{2}$$
$$\text{Arg}\sqrt{|z|}\frac{|z|+z}{||z|+z|}=\text{Arg}(1+e^{i\phi})$$
equality $\text{Arg}(1+e^{i\phi})=\frac{\phi}{2}$shows the drawing:

### [image]